# How to make an environment that can do conditionnal formatting for MCQs

Tags: formatting, environments, conditionals

I would like to preface by saying I am almost completely new to LaTeX.

Now, I am currently trying to make a document class for the Question Papers structure that is popular here. There are two kinds, and one of them is for MCQs.
Now, there are two kinds of MCQs, one that has a question and 4 options, the other, 3 statements with 4 options with different combinations of the statements. E.g.,

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to make an environment that will format the ordinary MCQ normally, and the other type when starred, or another way. Now, the options should be formatted differently depending on their length. Could someone tell me how I might go about making this environment?

As it is not quite simple in structure, I imagine I would need to define commands that assign the different values to variables in the `begin` section of the environment and format the question with the variables finally in the `end` section, but I am not entirely sure if that's the most optimal way.

Comment: Okay, so, due to the asinine and childish decisions of the department of our government that regulates internet and stuff, Imgur is banned here (so is reddit, by the way), and I can't see if the images I dragged onto my question is visible. So, please do tell me if you can't see 3 images containing the structure of the MCQs.

Comment: Your images are indeed visible.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for telling me!